# Find the average value between each element of the array and its immediate neighbor

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

Suppose I have a matrix 1a1 which is 1 x n, and I want to find the average value between each element of `a` and its neighbors.

What's a smart way to do this?

EX:

If

```
a=[0 1 2 1 0 1];
```

Then the "average value matrix" is:

```
b=[0.5 1 1.33 1 0.5];
```

Where the first entry of `b` is:

```
b(1) = (0+1)/2 = 0.5
b(2) = (0+1+2)/3 = 1
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing the middle as vector ops and handling the edge conditions as scalars.

```
    b=zeros(size(a));
    b(2:end-1)=(a(1:end-2)+a(2:end-1)+a(3:end))/3;
    b(1)=(a(1)+a(2))/2;
    b(end)=(a(end-1)+a(end))/2;
```

If you get into bigger averages...

```
    % scale and sum elements with a sliding window 3 long.
    b=conv(a,[1,1,1]/3)
    %
    % remove the tails
    b=b(2:end-1)
    % 
    % and rescale the edge cases.
    b(1)=b(1)*3/2
    b(end)=b(end)*3/2
```

I compared the first method above(vector),  the convolution method, and the hankel method suggested by RDizzl3.  (Sorry Luis,  I don't have the Statistics package, though I expect the nanmean method to be slower due to the amount of condition checking.)    The comparison was with a 10000 length random a vector, to make the timing significant.  b was initialized to a zeros matrix of the correct size before these timings were done.The hankel matrix(h) of correct size was precomputed before the these timings as well.

```
    % hankle method
    tic; b(1)=mean(a([1,2])); b(2:(n-1))=mean(a(h),2); b(2)=mean(a([n-1,n])); toc
    Elapsed time is 0.001698 seconds.
    % convolution method
    tic; c=conv(a,[1,1,1]/3) ; b=c(2:(2+n-1)); b(1)=b(1)*3/2; b(n)=b(n)*3/2; toc;
    Elapsed time is 0.000339 seconds.
    % vector method
    tic; b(1)=mean(a([1,2])) ; b(2:(n-1))=(a(1:(n-2))+a(2:(n-1))+a(3:n))/3;b(2)=mean(a([n-1,n])); toc
    Elapsed time is 0.000914 seconds.
```

I repeated the above 3 more times and sorted the results,

```
    hankel       convolution  vector
    9.2500e-04   3.3900e-04   7.2600e-04
    1.3820e-03   5.2600e-04   8.7100e-04
    1.6980e-03   5.5200e-04   9.1400e-04
    2.1570e-03   5.5300e-04   2.6390e-03
```

I am a little surprised,  I didn't expect the efficiency of the convolution approach to come out till larger window sizes.   But it consistently did the best here.

Note that if you are using smaller data sets these timings probably aren't appropriate.  I wouldn't at all be surprised if the hankel approach works better if the interest is in large numbers of shorter length vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
a=[0 1 2 1 0 1];
n = numel(a);
h = hankel(1:(n-2),(n-2):n);
b(1) = mean(a([1 2]))
b(2:(n-1)) = mean(a(h),2);
b(n) = mean(a([n-1 n]))
```

This will return the vector:

```
b =  [0.5000    1.0000    1.3333    1.0000    0.6667    0.5000]
```

This takes the elements from the vector `a` and finds the average for its neighbors, so:

```
b(1) = (0+1)/2 = 0.5
b(2) = (0+1+2)/3 = 1
b(3) = (1+2+1)/3 = 1.3333
b(4) = (2+1+0)/3 = 1
b(5) = (1+0+1)/3 = 0.6667
b(6) = (0+1)/2 = 0.5 % last element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0 1 2 1 0 1]; %// data
n = 1; %// how many neighbours to consider on each side

a2 = [NaN(1,n) a NaN(1,n)]; %// pad with NaN's (which will be ignored by nanmean)
b = arrayfun(@(k) nanmean(a2(k-n:k+n)), n+1:n+numel(a)); %// apply a
%// sliding-window mean ignoring NaN's
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use **smooth** filter

```
output=smooth(A,3,'moving');
```

where 3 is the **window size** (should be **odd** value)

check documentation for smooth function

https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html